# How to get Gaudium and Dolorium points?

Tags: trulon

Facing one of the bosses early in the game, I turned back to do some grinding. Walking around the map looking for trouble, I found several "Somethings" to investigate. In the beginning I found a few "Orbs" containing GD points(Gaudium and Dolorium?) and experience. There where also some pla monsters. When grinding on, the orbs became rarer, but the monsters kept coming. I was able to level up, but I also spent my GD - and now I cant find a refill of GD points anywhere!

Do I have to face the boss with 0 GD points now? Or is there some source of GD or resting that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next update will have gd/dr condensers at some towns. Until then i guess random encounters are the best way to refill. To back it up at this point I have nothing else than that I spoke with the devs last week that this issue will be rectified along with the random encounter exit bug and some others.

I just asked Arto on skype about the random encounter treasures. There is a set number of treasure encounters and after that game only spawns battles. So yeah, I guess it's better to wait for the next update or start over and save the GD until when you REALLY need it. Also remember that if you get past Borderlands do not enter random encounters before Shindusk at least. That will again be fixed with the update. How I know about it? Believe it or not, I created the world of Trulon :D

Comment: Do you have one or more references to help back this up?

Comment: Yeah, @MCMadman - but I have played some more, and is still not coming any more orbs in random encounters. They came in the beginning of my grinding, but now there is no random orbs at all anymore. -Will have to wait for the next update then. How do you know about the next update, BTW?

Comment: Excited to get my first ever Arquade question answered by the creator of the game :) Looking forward to the next Trulon update!

Comment: @MCMadman, do you know when the next release will be on AppStore?